# How to assign an object of class as string operator to variable?

Tags: c#, string, class, operators, overloading

I have class which have properties.

For Example

```
class Caption
{  
   public string AR{get;set;}
   public string EN{get;set;}
   pbulic string Tu{get;set;}   
}
```

i want for example Assign Caption object to vairable directly without need to call property

I want use This

```
Caption caption=new Caption();
string myVar = caption;   // this will return EN property directly
```

Rather Than

```
string myVar = caption.En;
```

I don't know but i think there's overload string operator or something for targeted class itself.

Why i need this ? just for localization's purposes and more readability in localization object.
rather every time creating `switch(language)` then assign `caption.EN`, `Caption.AR`. it will be ugly.

Comment: You can add a constructor that accepts, for example, a `CultureInfo` argument. Override `ToString()` to return the Caption in the language specified in the constructor. You can store all the strings corrensponding to a text in a specific culture in a Dictionary instead of using a public property for each culture. It's easier to load from a JSON file, too.

Comment: You can override the ToString() method in the Caption class, but then you would have to say string myVar = caption.ToString() to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way might be to implement an indexer. That way you can `switch` a single time, do whatever checks on the `language`, handle issues, deal with defaults, etc. inside the `Caption` class without the ceremony of calling a method, like so:

```
class Caption
{
    public string AR { get; set; }
    public string EN { get; set; }
    public string Tu { get; set; }

    // var cap = new Caption()[language];
    public string this[string language]
    {
        get
        {
            var which = AR;
            switch(language)
            {
                case nameof(EN):
                    which = EN;
                    break;
                case nameof(Tu):
                    which = Tu;
                    break;
            }
            return which;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that it's possible to achieve the syntax you're after where you can implicitly convert a `Caption` to a `string`. The caveat is that you'd need to know the `language` at some point before you do the conversion.

You can do so by providing a constructor that handles it on creation and/or with a method (chain-able if you wish) like I do below with `For`:

```
class Caption
{
    public string AR { get; set; }
    public string EN { get; set; }
    public string Tu { get; set; }

    // Gets the caption of the current language
    public string Current { get; private set; }

    // If the language is known in advance, you can return
    // the desired language directly.
    public static implicit operator string(Caption caption) 
        => caption.Current;

    public Caption For(string language)
    {
        var which = AR;
        switch (language)
        {
            case nameof(EN):
                which = EN;
                break;
            case nameof(Tu):
                which = Tu;
                break;
        }
        Current = which;
        return this;
    }
}

// Usage
var cap = new Caption
{ 
    AR = "Test-ar",
    EN = "Test-en",
    Tu = "Test-tu"        
}.For("EN");

string s = cap;
Console.WriteLine(s); // Test-en
```

Comment: Just so that I understand - what is the benefit of the indexer over say a method in the class GetLanguageString(string strLanguage) that pretty has the same method body as the indexer.

Comment: @Rakesh, convenience is the primary benefit but of course a method would work fine if that's preferred. Based on their wish to get the value as directly as possible, I'd rather do `caption[lang]` rather than `caption.GetLanguageString(lang)`.

Comment: Got it, never used an indexer myself, so was wondering if there was more under the hood.

Comment: Thats what i need excactly. Chief !   Thats make a class used as string ! that what i need, Thanks.

Comment: @devmuhammadkamal, glad it helped you. I updated the answer to add a bit on the implicit conversion; it may work for your case and be *exactly* what you're looking for :)